# Style recaptcha wrapping div

Tags: javascript, css, recaptcha

I have a problem with styling recaptcha wrapper.  As you can see on the image, the recaptcha is rendered in a wrapping div. I have to style it somehow... is there a way to remove this div or style it somehow?

I tried to use
`document.getElementById` or `document.getElementsByClassName`, but this div doesnt have any identificator or class...

[image]

Comment: Did you tried with I'd. We didn't see any id here..

Comment: Tried to check without any styling first... With a clean approach first

Answer (score 2):

From your image alone, here's a selector for that `<div>`:

```
script[src="main.js"] + div { ... }
```

Other valid ones:

```
body > div:last-of-type { ... }
/* or */
body > div:last-child { ... }
```

---

**Side note:** (for future questions) Never post images of code on [SO]. They're an insult to anyone who might have to type that code in order to help you. They could have copy/pasted if you cared to post it as code.

Comment: In this particular case, image instead of a code is fine. Thanks!

Comment: In this particular case, it was for the better (cause chances are you wouldn't have posted the previous `<script>` tag or the fact it was last `<div>` in `<body>` :). Most welcome! Stay safe.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a parent of an element, for example:

```
const div = document.querySelector('.grecaptcha-badge').parentNode;
```